How can extract data single line from file and other process in each that line?
i have log file with contents inside. i.e file name is convert.20231010.log.
The content inside file as below
2024-05-17 00:14:02.447 Success ABCXYZ15 on hard disk
2024-05-17 00:14:02.447 Fail at /home/category1/sub1/ABCXYZ01 00054 is not found
2024-05-17 00:14:02.447 Success ABCXYZ16 00030 on hard disk
2024-05-17 00:14:02.447 Fail at /home/category1/sub2/ABCXYZ02 is not found
2024-05-17 00:14:02.447 Success ABCXYZ17 000110 on hard disk

I want to check file and do some work on that.
a) find line in log with condition "Fail" and "is not found", get path and file name.
grep -E 'Fail.*is not found' convert.20231010.log

found 2 line with right condition
2024-05-17 00:14:02.447 Fail at /home/category1/sub1/ABCXYZ01 00054 is not found
2024-05-17 00:14:02.447 Fail at /home/category1/sub2/ABCXYZ02 is not found

b) pickup file from path and check file content
the path and file name will pickup from category2 based on founding at step a
/home/category2/sub1/ABCXYZ01 00054
/home/category2/sub2/ABCXYZ02

c) move file if content is good
Based on step b, read content file "ABCXYZ01 00054" and "ABCXYZ02" . If content is good , move file to category3. The content checking inside file is "CARD", if really have value, then file is good. If "CARD" is blank or empty, don't move that file.
ID=ABCXYZ01 00054
NAME=JOIN
DEPT=ACC
CARD=1234
LOC=NY

ID=ABCXYZ02
NAME=CINDY
DEPT=LOG
CARD=6789
LOC=LA

mv -f '/home/category2/sub1/ABCXYZ01 00054' '/home/category3/sub1/'
mv -f '/home/category2/sub2/ABCXYZ02' '/home/category3/sub2/'

d) remove line in log file
this one will remove 2 line in log file at step a
sed -i '/Fail.*is not found/d' convert.20231010.log

How can i do with bash shell in linux and write new log from step from a to d ? I'm not familiar with shell, appreciate for your help.
#!/bin/bash
MYSELF=$0
MYNAME=`echo $0 | gawk '{print substr($0, match($0, /[^\/]+$/))}'`
MYNAME_NOEXT=`echo "$MYNAME" | gawk '{print gensub(/\.[^\.]*$/, "", "g")}'`
MYPATH=`echo $0 | gawk '{print substr($0, 1, match($0, /[^\/]+$/) - 1)}'`
if [ $MYPATH == "./" ]; then MYPATH="`pwd`/"; fi
cd $MYPATH

logfile="/home/category4/logs/"$MYNAME_NOEXT.`date +"%Y%m%d"`.log

(
if [ `ps -ef | grep -i "$MYNAME" | wc -l` -gt 4 ]
then 
    echo $(date +%Y-%m-%d) $(date +%H:%M:%S)" - Script '$MYNAME' is running. Force exit as re-entry not allowed."
    exit
fi

filename="convert".`date +"%Y%m%d"`.log
while read -r line; do
    linetext="$line"
    echo "single line in log - $linetext"
done 

echo $(date) " - Script '$MYNAME' is ended normally."
) >> $logfile 2>&1


Please only ask one question per post. Each of your problems is individually covered by existing questions; please search before asking. Also, your script has a number of stylistic issues; try https://shellcheck.net/ and see also Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization

so, i said that i'm not familiar with shell, that why i'm asking . If can not , pls exception it. Thank so much.

Stop using backticks.  Use $() syntax for command substitution.

Untested since I don't have and don't want to create the directory structure your script and input file would require for testing:
Using GNU awk for the non-POSIX extensions of a 3rd arg to match() plus nextfile since the OP has now told us their log file is huge:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r file; do
    [[ -f "$file" ]] &&
    >&2 echo mv -f -- "$file" '/home/category3/sub1/'
done < <(
    awk '
        NR == FNR {
            if ( match($0,/Fail at (.*) is not found/,a) ) {
                ARGV[ARGC++] = a[1]
            }
            else {
                print > "newlog.txt"
            }
            next
        }
        /^CARD=[0-9]/ {
            print FILENAME
            nextfile
        }
    ' convert.20231010.log
)

If you don't have GNU awk then do this instead with any awk which will just run a bit slower if your awk doesn't support nextfile (few other awks support a 3rd arg to match() but many support nextfile and the nextfile statement will do nothing if not supported so it's harmless):
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r file; do
    [[ -f "$file" ]] &&
    >&2 echo mv -f -- "$file" '/home/category3/sub1/'
done < <(
    awk '
        BEGIN {
            beg = "Fail at "
            end = " is not found"
            begLgth = length(beg)
            allLgth = length(beg end)
        }
        NR == FNR {
            if ( match($0,beg ".*" end) ) {
                ARGV[ARGC++] = substr($0,RSTART+begLgth,RLENGTH-allLgth)
            }
            else {
                print > "newlog.txt"
            }
            next
        }
        /^CARD=[0-9]/ {
            print FILENAME
            nextfile
        }
    ' convert.20231010.log
)

The [[ -f "$file" ]] && in the shell loop protects us from any issue if the same file name appears multiple times in the input, or /^CARD=[0-9]/ matches multiple times in 1 file and your awk doesn't support nextfile, and so we may have already moved it at that point in the shell loop.
Original answer:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

regexp='Fail at (.*) is not found'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    file=""
    [[ $line =~ $regexp ]] && file="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    if [[ -f "$file" ]] && ! grep -q '^CARD=[0-9]' "$file"; then
        >&2 echo mv -f -- "$file" '/home/category3/sub1/'
    else
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
    fi
done < convert.20231010.log > newlog.txt

Remove the >&2 echo when you're done testing and sure the script will do what you want.

Another (possibly extremely inconvenient) method for testing is to add -i to the invocation of mv.

Hi @Ed Morton, what's this line [[ $line =~ $regexp ]] && file="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

tests if the contents of the variable line, e.g. 2024-05-17 00:14:02.447 Fail at /home/category1/sub1/ABCXYZ01 00054 is not found, match the contents of the variable regexp, Fail at (.*) is not found, and, if so, set file to whatever part of line matched the .* within parens in regexp, i.e. /home/category1/sub1/ABCXYZ01. It's like doing file=$(printf '%s\n' "$line" | sed -n 's/.*Fail at \(.*\) is not found.*/\1/p') but with bash builtins instead of the external commands and extra process.

Ok, i got it. Btw, my log very huge with ~1mil lines. So far, can not use while IFS= read -r line; do ....done , very slow if size files very big, the number of lines in file so huge. Somehow , can using grep ""Fail at (.*) is not found first, this very quick, found 2 lines with right condition. After that, continute process only those 2 lines.  @EdMorton

You should have said in your question that your input file was huge and so execution speed was a big factor. I added a new script that'll be orders of magnitude faster than the original one.
